# The Counter in My Program is being Improperly Doubled

Tags: c, if-statement

When the user their money, the program is supposed to store the money. The program stops once it reaches the target money which is $100. But, for some reason, my program is doubling the money. This is the output: "***Welcome! Are you looking to donate or do you work here?
donate
Great! How munch? $50

We already met our target but thanks!".
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int charityMoney=0;
   int target=100;
   char descision[20];


   //figuring out whether you want to donate or not
   //the loop will keep on going until the target is met
   while(charityMoney <= target)
    {

       printf("***Welcome! Are you looking to donate or do you work here?\n");
       scanf("%s", &descision);

        if((strcmp(descision, "donate") == 0))
           {
               printf("Great! How munch? $");
               scanf("%d", &charityMoney);
               charityMoney += charityMoney;

          }
          else if((strcmp(descision, "work here") == 0))
            {
                printf("Total donated so far: $%d",  charityMoney);
          } else if(strcmp(descision, "exit")){
                printf("Bye!");
                exit(0);
          }

          if(charityMoney == target)
          {
              printf("\n We already met our target but thanks!");
              exit(0);
          }

    return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `charityMoney += charityMoney;` this is doubling the amount. Not sure why you wrote it if it's not what you want the code to do

Comment: You need two variables. One for the total, and another for the answer to the question. Then add the answer to the total each time through the loop.

Comment: You will want to create a separate variable for the donation amount and add that to `charityMoney`,

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
        printf("Great! How much? $");
        int donation = 0;
        scanf("%d", &donation);
        charityMoney += donation;
```